Dissection proof of Heron's formula?
In his recent book, Love Triangle, Matt Parker playfully complains that Heron's formula is an "opaque formula, and I feel like you just chuck in the side-lengths, turn a series of arbitrary mathematical handles, and out pops the answer. It works, but it's not satisfying." Parker's remark got me thinking about whether there might be some kind of equidecomposition lurking beneath the surface.
Recall that Heron's formula says that the area of a triangle $ABC$ with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ (where side $a$ is opposite $A$ and so on; I abuse notation by using the same letter for the name of the side and its length) is $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$, where $s=(a+b+c)/2$ is the semi-perimeter. Now, if we let $r$ be the inradius of $ABC$, then it is easy to see that the area of $ABC$ is $rs$. Therefore, Heron's formula may be rewritten
$$\eqalignno{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c) &= r^2s.&(*)\cr}$$

Is there a nice way to dissect a (rectangular) cuboid with sides $s-a$, $s-b$, $s-c$ into finitely many pieces and reassemble them into a (rectangular) cuboid with sides $r$, $r$, $s$?

A couple of remarks:

Every rectangular cuboid has Dehn invariant zero, so the desired scissors congruence certainly exists; the question is whether there is a "nice" dissection, ideally one that could form the basis for a (new?) proof of Heron's formula.
The quantities $s-a$, $s-b$, $s-c$ have natural geometric interpretations; if $X$, $Y$, $Z$ denote the points of tangency of the incircle on sides $a$, $b$, $c$ respectively, then $s-a = AY = AZ$ and $s-b = BX = BZ$ and $s-c = CX = CY$.
EDIT Oct 15, 2024: I just learned of two papers that are soon to appear in Mathematics Magazine: "A Synthetic Geometry Proof of Heron’s Formula" by Colin Beveridge, and "An Astonishing Proof of Heron’s Formula" by Wagner Oliveira Costa Filho. But neither of these proofs involves a dissection of 3-dimensional solids.


But if instead of $sr$ you use the formula $\sqrt{sr} \cdot \sqrt{(s-a) r_a} $ for the area, you reduce Heron formula not to (*) but to much easier equation $(s-b) (s-c) =rr_a$ which follows from a pair if similar right triangles (which if course can be proved by dissection)

@FedorPetrov What is $r_a$?

Radius of excircle, so area is $(s-a) r_a$

More generally, should there be a dissection proof of Brahmagupta's formula for the area of a cyclic quadrilateral?

@FedorPetrov Thanks. Your comment is useful, though I am still interested in my original question as stated, in part because it feels more "symmetric" to me.

I wondered about this before, but I thought about dissecting in 4 dimensions (because there are 4 factors in the square root). More generally, considering Cayley–Menger determinant for computing the volume of n-dimensional simplex suggest it is more natural to consider the square of the volume. Can we prove it with a dissection proof in 2n dimensions?

If the circumscribed circle has diameter $1,$ then the area is $4$ times the product of the lengths of the sides. Does that have anything to do with this?

Heron's formula says the area of a triangle whose sides have lengths $a,b,c$ is
$$
\frac14\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)}.
$$
It is true that this is an "opaque formula" with which you "just chuck in the side-lengths, turn a series of arbitrary mathematical handles, and out pops the answer," about which one should say "It works, but it's not satisfying."?
Notice that

One must expect an expression that is homogeneous of degree $2$ as a function of $a,b,c.$
$(a+b+c)$ should be a factor because the area is $0$ when $a=b=c=0.$
$(a+b-c)$ should be a factor because when $a+b=c$ you have a degenerate triangle, whose area is $0.$
The other factors must be there for the same reason.
The number $1/4$ is seen to be right when one considers $a=b=c=1.$

This is not a dissection proof, but it addresses the first issue raised in the original posting.

The argument for the $a+b+c$ factor is faulty, as polynomials that vanish at $(0,0,0)$ are not necessarily multiples of $a+b+c$; indeed, the other three factors already make the expression $0$ when $a=b=c=0$. The constraints you list would be satisfied e.g. by the wrong formula $(s-a)\sqrt{(s-b)(s-c)}$ (scaled by a suitable constant).

Also, the reasoning does not explain why we should expect a square root of a polynomial of degree $4$, rather than, say, a cube root of a polynomial of degree $6$, or even a more complicated algebraic function.

$(s-a)\sqrt{(s-b)(s-c)}$ can be ruled out as it is not symmetric, but one can consider e.g. $((s-a)(s-b)(s-c))^{2/3}$ instead.

Hmm. One could argue that it should be in an iterated quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q(a,b,c)$ as it is constructible with a ruler and a compass. In that case, consider e.g. $\sqrt[4]{(a^5+b^5+c^5)(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$.

@EmilJeřábek : I think if I ponder this for a few decades, I can probably come up with a cogent reason why it ought to be the simplest thing that meets some simple desiderata, and your thing involving fifth powers is not simple enough.

The area is (half) the product of a side by the height, so the question of why we get square roots boils down to why the height is a square root.  This can be tracked down by applying Pythagoras to both right triangles made by the height.

Although this argument is not a complete proof that this particular function is the one, does it show that Matt Parker's pessimistic assessment is mistaken?

@MichaelHardy In my opinion, your argument at best has the form of a sanity check, similar to the way dimensional analysis of certain formulas in physics provides a sanity check. In my mind, a sanity check is only a small step toward an explanation. For comparison, we know from elementary Newtonian mechanics that kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2} mv^2$, so by dimensional analysis we see that $E = mc^2$ also makes sense. But if that's the only justification we have for $E = mc^2$ then the formula remains mysterious.

The argument can be made rigorous under the assumption that the square of the area is a polynomial $f(a,b,c)$. It, indeed, has to be homogeneous of degree $4$, and divisible by the square-free polynomials $a+b-c$, $a+c-b$, $b+c-a$ as it vanishes on ${(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^3:a,b,c\ge0,a+b=c}$, and this set is Zariski dense in ${(a,b,c)\in\mathbb C^3:a+b=c}$ (this is intuitively clear, and easy to prove). The argument for the $a+b+c$ factor in the answer is thouroughly nonsensical, but it can be circumvented as follows: we already know $f(a,b,c)=(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)g(a,b,c)$ ...

... for some polynomial $g$, and $g$ has to be a symmetric homogeneous linear polynomial, thus the only possibility is that it is a scalar multiple of $a+b+c$.

@TimothyChow : I wonder if you understood what I meant by "does it show that Matt Parker's pessimistic assessment is mistaken?". Note what Matt Parker wrote: "opaque formula, and I feel like you just chuck in the side-lengths, turn a series of arbitrary mathematical handles, and out pops the answer. It works, but it's not satisfying." My argument is not a proof, maybe even at an "intuitive" level but Matt Parker seems to think the formula is an arbitrary hodge-podge, and it seems to me that what I wrote should at least show that it's better than that.

@MichaelHardy Matt Parker's YouTube channel is entitled "Stand-up Maths", and while he does try to be accurate, he's not above a bit of overstatement for rhetorical effect. In particular, I don't think he's claiming that the formula is an "arbitrary hodge-podge"; it's true, after all! I also think Parker would appreciate the street-fighting mathematics character of your observations, and regard it as a first step toward removing the opacity, but maybe not more than that.

Noam Elkies pointed out to me by email that there cannot exist a dissection (of the type I asked for) using bounded number of pieces. Consider a triangle with sides $T+1$, $T+1$, $2T$, so $s=2T+1$ and $r\approx \sqrt{T/2}.$ Then we are trying to dissect a cuboid $X$ with sides $T$, $T$, $1$ into a cuboid $Y$ with sides $\sqrt{T/2}$, $\sqrt{T/2}$, $2T+1$. It is then intuitively clear that since $X$ has thickness $1$, it is "too thin" relative to $Y$ for any dissection into $C$ pieces—where $C$ is a constant independent of $T$—to work. (A rigorous proof is a bit tricky; it's an old chestnut to show that a disc of diameter $D$ cannot be covered with fewer than $D$ rectangles of width $1$.)
On the other hand, it's still conceivable that by adding some auxiliary pieces $Z$, there might be a scissors congruence between $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$ using a bounded number of pieces.

Along with $S=rs$, there is a formula for the area $S=r_a(s-a)$, where $r_a$ is the corresponding exradius. Thus, $S=\sqrt{rs\cdot r_a(s-a)}$, and Heron's formula reads as $(s-b)(s-c)=rr_a$. This follows from the similarity of right triangles $BE_aX_{AB}$ and $IBI_c$, which in turn may be proved by dissection if you like.


I have been told that one of the reasons for the early popularity of Heron's formula was that it became a trade secret for Islamic lawyers, seeing that when a man died his land had to be divided equally among his sons. Triangulation and Heron's formula provided lawyers with a straightforward procedure for reckoning area.

But why they did not partition it to right triangles for which area formula is much easier?

@FedorPetrov Maybe the land was not necessarily rectangular.

@user127776 but everything which is partitioned onto triangles may be partitioned onto right triangles

@FedorPetrov Drawing perpendicular lines on land might not have been easy, since you need to identify the intersection point. (At least I have no idea how to do it without an image from above.)

also when dividing land you don't want to split it to tiny disconnected components so that each person's share could be disconnected.

Identifying the intersection point is very easy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem . You don’t even have to split the trinagles into right-angled triangles as such; you simply drop the altitude so that you can measure it, and then computing the area is trivial. In ancient or medieval times, this would have been certainly easier than dealing with the square root in Heron’s formula. The whole story smacks of an unfounded legend.

Since this thread seems to have developed into a discussion of simple approaches to Heron, let me  add my two cents.  There is a very easy way to derive (even obtain from scratch) Heron´s formula and indeed to extend it to  formulae in terms of the side lengths for ANY triangle quantity .  If we denote the vertices by $A_1,A_2,A_3$
and the corresponding side lengths by $e_{12},e_{23},e_{31}$, then we can suppose that the former have coordinates  $(0,0)$,$(e_{12},0)$ and $(p,q)$ for some $p,q$.  One has  equations $e_{23}^2=(p-e_{12})^2+q^2$ and $e_{31}^2=p^2+q^2$ which can  be solved in a matter of seconds to obtain $p$ and $q$ in terms of the side lengths.  The area is  $\frac 12 q e_{12}$ which can now  be expressed as a function of the side lengths. Any triangle quantity (by this I mean any real number associated with a triangle--trigonometric functions of the angles, altitudes, median lengths, etc.--which can be computed  from the coordinates of the vertices) can be expressed in terms of the side lengths in a similar manner, namely  by calculating it for the above triangle as a function of $p,q,e_{12}$ and then substituting for $p$ and
$q$.
As a bonus, the same method can be used to express the volume of a tetrahedron, and indeed any other tetrahedral quantity, in terms of the side lengths (one supposes that the vertices are $(0,0,0)$,$(e_{12},0,0)$,$(p,q,0)$,$(r,s,t)$ and solves for $p,q,r,s,t$ in terms of the side lengths).  In this case, the computations are rather more tedious but they can be done.  If one is prepared to use Mathematica, then it is again a matter of seconds.
The same techniques cannot be applied to quadrilaterals since they are not rigid but one can use them for certain subclasses, notably for cyclic quadrilaterals (though there are some additional subtleties in this case).
